# Is it possible to force use of overflow menu to the right of software button?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have an action bar with many options and a menu.
On devices that don't have menu button, the overflow menu is added to my action bar.

I want to add this overflow menu button to the right of the software buttons, just like application that don't have an action bar, like this :

[image: overflow meny button to the right of software buttons]

Is it possible, and, if it's possible, how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible

Yes, if you do not mind your app looking like you are no longer maintaining it, thereby reducing your prospective user base.

Please read [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), particularly this passage:

> However, this button doesn’t provide an ideal user experience. In fact, in apps that don’t use an options menu anyway, this action overflow button does nothing and creates user confusion. So you should update your legacy apps to remove the action overflow from the navigation bar when running on Android 3.0+ and begin using the action bar if necessary. You can do so all while remaining backward compatible with the devices your apps currently support.

Talented developers, therefore, are trying to *avoid* putting that affordance in the system/navigation bar, not adding that affordance.

> how to do this ?

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` and your `android:minSdkVersion` to something less than 11.

Comment: Am I wrong or this is no longer possible? Im doing as you say but the menu icon does not appear on my tablet (that does not have menu hardware button)

Comment: @ernestocattaneo: AFAIK, the "menu button of shame" should still be available, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: it looks like it does not work anymore.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367271/android-overflow-not-showing-on-action-bar

Comment: @ernestocattaneo: Your `minSdkVersion` is 16. 16 is higher than 11. Your `targetSdkVersion` **and** your `minSdkVersion` have to be lower than 11, as you can see in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: thanks to be clear. But... how do I do? haha I mean.. if a tablet running my app does not have menu button... he won't be able to open the menu... what the hell...

Comment: @ernestocattaneo: "how do I do?" -- to change 16 to 11, I would use the BACKSPACE key and the 1 key. "if a tablet running my app does not have menu button... he won't be able to open the menu" -- if the device has an on-screen navigation bar, the "menu button of shame" will be added to it. I have not tried using this on a device that does not have an on-screen navigation bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70393/discussion-between-ernestocattaneo-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

This button is automatically added by Android if your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are less than API 11. The only exception is that if you set `minSdkVersion` to 10 or lower, set `targetSdkVersion` to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

If your `targetSdkVersion` and/or `minimumSdkVersion` are at or over API 11, then you cannot use this button.

Comment: I would be more interested how does this happens, what change does system do to add the overflow menu. In that particular case where my  minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, and targetSdkVersion set to 11, 12, or 13.