# ANDROID: Overflow not showing on action bar

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-actionbar, android-menu

I need that if the tablet does not have the menu hardware button... it will show the menu button on the software buttons as you see here:

[image]

So I've googled a bit and found out that to display this button you only need to:

*"set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher."*

*"Set your android:targetSdkVersion and your android:minSdkVersion to something less than 11."*

I've tried both but nothing works. I don't understand why. Maybe because the minimum SDK of my application is: API16 Android 4.1 ?

**Can anybody give me an hint of why this is not working?**

Answer (score 0):

**That Works only when your application is backwards compatible with Ginger Bread (2.3).**

Comment: target 2.3 but it's rarely an option.

Comment: you are saying that If I have a menu called from the menu button... and the tablet that's running my application does not have a menu button... the menu can't be opened? o.O

Comment: Yeah but why worry when you have the action bar.

Comment: if you want to then make it backwards compatible , when i said rarely an option i meant that you might lose access to many methods which work on higher API's.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have an action bar :D it is hidden!!

Comment: Hidden ..but why ? I think you mean it doesn't exist in 2.3 in that case use actionbarcompat